# Animation settings questions in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

First

[image]

Second

[image]

Third

[image]

Fourth

[image]

Other people made two "make transition" in "Any State" that you see in the picture, and I could only make one.

I'm going to make an animation change by clicking.

How can I set 'make transition' to 'male_idle_pant' and 'male_move_run_sprint' at the same time?

ex))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `Any state` or any other state then you can right click to get the option for `Make Transition`

I am unable to record the cursor
[image: Gif to show the transition]

Comment: I did, but I couldn't solve it.
And I edited the question.

Comment: I can`t Click Any state.

Comment: So, in your fourth screen shot you cannot select `Any State`?

Comment: It works well when I lowered the version. I think it was because of the bug. I can't do it only in 2020.3.32f1 version.